# Why is List[Int] an instance of List[Boolean]?

Tags: scala

As I played a bit with the Scala REPL (Scala 2.9.1) I saw a surprising result with the isInstanceOf method:

```
scala> val l = List[Int](1, 2, 3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l.isInstanceOf[List[Int]]
warning: there were 1 unchecked warnings; re-run with -unchecked for details
res3: Boolean = true

scala> l.isInstanceOf[List[String]]
warning: there were 1 unchecked warnings; re-run with -unchecked for details
res4: Boolean = true

scala> l.isInstanceOf[List[Boolean]]
warning: there were 1 unchecked warnings; re-run with -unchecked for details
res5: Boolean = true
```

Can anyone explain the last two results ?

Comment: Type erasure. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens

Comment: "re-run with -unchecked for details". Did you do it?

Comment: To blame myself: No, I did not. I could not figure out how to do that. If I use "compile -unchecked" at the sbt shell, it does not know this option. Where do I have to place this option ?

Comment: Just call the Scala REPL with that additional argument: `scala -unchecked`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Is there a way to start the Scala REPL out of sbt with the unchecked option, too ? Within the sbt shell, the command 'console -unchecked' will fail.

Comment: @JohnThreepwood That's worth another question, but you just have to set `scalacOptions`. On `build.sbt`, `scalacOptions += "-unchecked"`. Or, from sbt console, `set scalacOptions += "-unchecked"`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

re-running with `-unchecked`:

```
scala> l.isInstanceOf[List[Int]]
<console>:9: warning: non variable type-argument Int in type List[Int] is 
unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
              l.isInstanceOf[List[Int]]
                        ^
```

The specific type of the object is just not known at runtime. This is a general feature/limitation of the generics mechanism provided by the JVM. See [Type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

It's due to type erasure which replaces the Int type parameter in List with the most generic type bound it can find. In this case, I believe that is scala.Any.

Note these will also yield true:

```
scala> l.isInstanceOf[List[scala.Nothing]]
warning: there were 1 unchecked warnings; re-run with -unchecked for details
res0: Boolean = true

scala> l.isInstanceOf[List[Any]]
warning: there were 1 unchecked warnings; re-run with -unchecked for details
res1: Boolean = true

scala> l.isInstanceOf[List[Object]]
warning: there were 1 unchecked warnings; re-run with -unchecked for details
res2: Boolean = true
```

Using javap to disassemble this simple class we can see that there is in fact no generic type in List[Int]:

```
class Bar{
  val list = List[Int](1,2,3)
}
```

The disassembled scala code:

```
public class Bar extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
  public scala.collection.immutable.List list();
  public Bar();
}
```